# Package "expo-image-picker" does not contain a valid config plugin

Tags: react-native, plugins, build, eas

I have a problem when I try to build my react native project,

I thought maybe there are additional libraries that limit me in the build process, but this is the problem I encountered.
I don't use android studio I use expo

[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10LLr.png)

This is the code in my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "scheme": "mycoolredirect",
    "name": "client",
    "slug": "client",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.PicaPlant.client"
    },
    "android": {
      "googleServicesFile":"./google-services.json",
      "package": "com.PicaPlant.client",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode":"pan"

    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "b4685540-68d2-4df4-bcbf-baac16b48c19"
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "photosPermission":
            "The app accesses your photos to let you share them with your friends."
        }
      ]
    ]
    },

   "plugins": [
    [
       "expo-notifications",
      {
         "icon": "./local/assets/icon.png",
        "color": "#ffffff"
   }
 ]
]
}
```

This the code in my EAS.json

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.7.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
      },
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug",
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      },
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Thanks!

I tried to change the plugin it didn't help, I tried to download packages again and update and that didn't help either